# How to get a link to a Github commit?

Tags: github

for the final paper for my project my teacher wants us to link our project artifacts/commits in our final report. How do I do this?

Comment: I am also new here, maybe I can help you if you clarify what you exactly need.
Do you need to give a shared link to your teacher?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. But is there a way to copy/paste the link to certain commits into my report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sharing a link, you just need to create a repository in GitHub then make a commit to the master branch. Make the repository public if the shared information is not something private, or you can make it private and ask your teacher for his/her username in GitHub and add as a collaborator. After committing, just share the link with your teacher and all the information will be available under that link.
I am also new to Stack Overflow, but one thing that I noticed is to choose the best title for your question so that others will find the similar question easily by googling.